# Додумать с площадями формул треугольника

Tags: c++

Ребят, Привет всем,
у меня тут запара, не могу понять до конца. Задача:**"Из заданного мн - ва точек на плоскости выбрать 3 разные точки A, B, C так, чтобы внутри треугольника ABC содержалось максимальное кол - во точек этого мн - ва."**
Я понял, что нужно делать через три треугольника и находить их площади, складывать их = получится треугольник и уже в нем все i, j, k сложить и будет количество точек, задача будет верна, так мне, по крайней мере, сказал преподователь. Не могу разобраться с тем, какие мне вершины нужно взять и как?
я могу сам не допереть то, что написал( в коде) если что, не ругайтесь, пишу, могу тупить
помогите разобраться, пожалуйста
про srand не пишите, знаю про ошибку)

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <cmath>
> #include <conio.h>
> #include <locale.h>
> #include <cstdlib>
> #include <time.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> using namespace std;
> int main()
> {
>     setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
>
>     int size;
>     const int size_arr_1 = 100, size_arr_2 =
>     100;
>     int n[size_arr_1][size_arr_2];
>
>     cout << "Введите размер множества точек:" << endl; //Ввод  пользователем размерность массива
>     cin >> size;
>
>     if (size > 0)
>     {
>         char random;
>         cout << "Массив заполнить случайными числами ? (y / n) \n";
>         cin >> random;
>         if (random == 'y')
>         {
>             int n[100];
>             srand(time(0));
>
>             for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
>                 n[i] = 1.0 + 4.0 * rand() / (int)RAND_MAX;
>
>             for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
>                 n[j] = 1.0 + 4.0 * rand() / (int)RAND_MAX;
>
>             for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
>                 cout << n[i] << " ";
>
>             for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
>                 cout << n[j] << " ";
>         }
>
>         else
>         {
>             for (int i = 0, j = 0, count = 1; i < size, j < size;
>                  i++, j++, count++)
>             {
>                 {
>                     cout << "Введите элементы массива[" << i << "]: ";
>                     cin >> n[i][j];
>                     cout << "Введите элементы массива[" << j << "]: ";
>                     cin >> n[i][j];
>                 }
>             }
>
>             for (int i = 1; i < size - 2; i++)
>             {
>                 for (int j = 1; j < size - 1; j++)
>                 {
>                     for (int k = 1; k < size; k++)
>                     {
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>             // Мне нужно найти площади трех треугольников и сложить их
>             // дабы определить в каком треугольнике какое количество точек
>         }
>         //}
>     }   else
>     {
>         cout << "Ввод данных неверен!\n"; }
>     _getch();
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: Никакие площади тут не нужны. Для лобового решения за n^4 понадобится только проверка вхождения точки в треугольник.

Comment: Это уже третий вопрос, полностью повторяющий предыдущие два...

Answer (score 0):

Просто чтобы вы не донимали всех еще и еще.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct point {
    double x, y;
    };

vector<point> task;

bool inTri(point p, point a, point b, point c) {
    double u = (a.x - p.x) * (b.y - a.y) - (b.x - a.x) * (a.y - p.y);
    double v = (b.x - p.x) * (c.y - b.y) - (c.x - b.x) * (b.y - p.y);
    double w = (c.x - p.x) * (a.y - c.y) - (a.x - c.x) * (c.y - p.y);
    return (u < 0 && v < 0 && w < 0) || (u > 0 && v > 0 && w > 0);
    }

int main() {
    int size = 100; // или cin >> size
    int l = 0, m = 0, n = 0, max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        task.push_back(point{1. + 4.*rand() / RAND_MAX,
                             1. + 4.*rand() / RAND_MAX});

    for (int i = 0; i < task.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < task.size(); ++j) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < task.size(); ++k) {
                int count = 0;

                for (int s = 0; s < task.size(); ++s) {
                    if (s == i || s == j || s == k) continue;

                    if (inTri(task[s], task[i], task[j], task[k])) count++;
                    }

                if (count > max) {
                    max = count;
                    l = i;
                    m = j;
                    n = k;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    cout
            << "max triangle:"
            << " (" << task[l].x << "," << task[l].y << ") "
            << " (" << task[m].x << "," << task[m].y << ") "
            << " (" << task[n].x << "," << task[n].y << ") "
            << max << " points inside" << endl;
    }
```